# Check if action goal is achieved in different node

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody
I am using nav2 FollowWaypoints action server to send some waypoints for my robot. Now I want to perform some task once action is finished (every waypoint has been achieved or not). How can I get information whether action is finished or not, but in a different node then the one sending goal (initial action client)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398486/check-if-action-goal-is-achieved-in-different-node/) by [sdudiak01](https://answers.ros.org/users/99350/sdudiak01/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2022-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can send a trigger message on a separate topic to a different node for each action feedback update from the initial action client. A pair of an updated class variable and a timer publisher should be enough.

Have you tried anything similar before like [there (Python)](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/action_tutorials/action_tutorials_py/action_tutorials_py/fibonacci_action_client.py) or [there (C++)](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/action_tutorials/action_tutorials_cpp/src/fibonacci_action_client.cpp)?

What problems did you encounter?

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdudiak01](https://answers.ros.org/users/99350/sdudiak01/) on 2022-04-06**:
I haven't tried anything you mentioned, but I was thinking to do it using a server request rather than a topic. Is this a good approach?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-06**:
Invoking a service inside the callback is not recommended in ROS as it stops everything else while processing. Normal topic publisher should be fine, I think e.g. some timer to see if there is an update of the last saved point reached by the robot and forward this information

**Comment by [sdudiak01](https://answers.ros.org/users/99350/sdudiak01/) on 2022-04-07**:
I will try it out and let you know how it went

**Comment by [sdudiak01](https://answers.ros.org/users/99350/sdudiak01/) on 2022-04-11**:
It works!!!. I added goal callbacks like [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Actions/Writing-a-Py-Action-Server-Client.html) and in goal callback I send a trigger message to another node. It's very simple, but works just fine.